# How to set up environment variables on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, httpresponse, heroku-api

When I deploy Node.js API on Heroku it gives me a wrong response .

```
res.json({"user":user,"auth-token":token});
```

**localhost:3000/auth/login**

```
{
"user": {
 "email": "name1@gmail.com",
 "username": "name1",
 "fullname": "fullname 1"
},
"auth-token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyaWQiOiI1ZjMxN2I0OTFhZTc4YzFjOWNjMjZjZWUiLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6Im5pa2hpbGt1bWEiLCJmdWxsbmFtZSI6Ik5pa2hpbCBrdW1hciBTaW5naCIsImlhdCI6MTU5ODI0OTA3M30"
}
```

After deploy on heroku

**name.herokuapp.com/auth/login**

```
{
"user": {
 "email": "name1@gmail.com",
 "username": "name1",
 "fullname": "fullname 1"
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code how you are getting token?

Comment: Can you show me the .env file and token generation code?

Comment: Looks like `token` is falsy, and thus it is removed from the final response. Can you check whether the JWT token generation is working correctly when you deploy on heroku?

Comment: @PrathameshMore thanks. Problem arise  due to I use jwt secret key mention in 
 .env file `jwt.verify(token,process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY);` when I just replace with simple string `jwt.verify(token,"sdfahflkhow8e90fr980");` its working correctly .

Comment: why .env file not working on heroku.

Comment: Hey, I added a solution! Don't upload .env file on Heroku. Heroku has `Config Vars`.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Your question says _nothing_ about environment variables outside of your title. Asking a clear question is the best way to improve your chances of getting a useful answer.

Comment: @Nikhilkumar Could you accept a solution so other developers would easily find this useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the following steps

Install package called `dotenv`

`npm install dotenv`

Load that module in the main file where you using like environment variable. e.g `process.env.PORT`

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
```

1. Now log in to Heroku account
2. Go to your project dashboard
3. Got to settings tab [image: heroku setting]
4. Now add your environment variables here

[image: environment variables]

Now put your `JWT_SECRET_KEY` key and value to the next textbox there.

Note: Put same names in here like .env file

Hope that will work!